# High- vs. low bit encoding for 10/12 bit images

Tags: image-processing

I had a discussion with a colleague recently on the topic of high-bit encodings vs. low bit encodings of 12 bit images in 16 bits of memory (e.g. PNG files). He argued that high-bit encodings were easier to use, since many image viewers (e.g. windows image preview, explorer thumbnails, ...) can display them more easily in a human-readable way using trivial 16-to-8 conversions, while low-bit encoded images appear mostly black.

I'm thinking more from an image processing perspective and thought that surely, low-bit encodings are better, so I sat down, did some experimentation and wrote out my findings. I'm curious if the community here has additional or better insights that I am missing.

1. When using some image processing backend (e.g. Intel IPP), 10 and 12 bit encodings are often assumed to physically take 16 bits (unsigned short). The memory is read as "a number", so that a gray value of 1 (12 bit) encoded in the low bits yields a "1", while encoded in the high bits it yields a 16 (effectively, left shift by four).
2. Taking a low-bit image and the corresponding left shifted high-bit image and performing some operations (possibly including interpolation) will yield identical results after right-shifting the result of the high-bit input (for comparison's sake).
3. The main differences come when looking at the histograms of the images: the low-bit histogram is "dense" and 4k entries long, the high-bit histogram contains 15 zeros for every non-zero entry, and is 65k entries long.

3 a) Generating lookup tables (LUTs) for operations takes 16x as long, applying them should take identical time.

3 b) Operations scaling with histrogram^2 (e.g. gray scale cooccurrence matrices) become much more costly: 256x memory and time if done naively (but then again, in order to correctly treat any potential interpolated pixels with values not allowed in the original 12 bit encoding correctly, you kind of have to...)

3 c) Debugging histogram vectors is a PITA when looking at mostly-zero interspersed high-bit histograms.

To my great surprise, that was all I could come up with. Anything obvious that I am missing?

Comment: Please read [ask].  I don't think your question: _"... Anything obvious that I am missing?..."_ as currently stated fits the SO Q&A format.  Also please remove the [C++] tag as nothing in the question is specific to C++.

Comment: I am on your side... From image processing perspective, it's better to put the significant bits in the lower part of the 16 bits. But the question doesn't fit Stack Overflow site.